# Запятая в "характеризует как"

Tags: пунктуация

Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться с постановкой запятой.

Этот поступок характеризует чиновников(,) как мелких людей.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В предложении нет сравнительного оборота. "Как мелких людей" употреблено в значении "в качестве мелких людей", поэтому запятая перед ***как*** не нужна.

***Этот поступок характеризует чиновников как мелких людей.***